# How to setup Moq for repository

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, repository-pattern

I have method

```
public IEnumerable<string> LoadCountries()
{
     try
     {
         return GetAll().GetCountries();
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
          return null;
     }
 }
```

GetAll() method load data from sql server but I don't need it in test
So i changed database on IEnumerable customers. I wanna test it

```
Mock<ICustomersRepository> mock = new Mock<ICustomersRepository>();
mock.Setup(m => m.GetAll()).Returns(customers.AsQueryable()); //change data
IEnumerable<string> countries = mock.Object.LoadCountries();
Assert.AreEqual(countries.Count(), 6); //expect 6 countries
```

But in this test countries.Count() == 0;
Sure I can modify Mock Setup and add

```
mock.Setup(m => m.LoadCountries()).Returns(customers.AsQueryable().GetCountries());
```

But I don't want to do it, because other functions that i want to test are much bigger.
Is anyone know how can set GetAll() function to return my test array, even if GetAll() implements inside test class?
I just try to set

```
mock.CallBase = true;
mock.Setup(m => m.LoadCountries()).CallBase();
```

but i just see exception

> System.NotImplementedException: This is a DynamicProxy2 error: 
>   The interceptor attempted to 'Proceed' for method
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String] LoadCountries()' which has no target. 
>   When calling method without target there is no implementation to 'proceed' to and 
>   it is the responsibility of the interceptor to mimic the implementation (set return
>   value, out arguments etc).

Comment: Side note - returning `null` in case of exception is not very good idea. You should log exception (otherwise it just be swallowed) and return something like Enumerable.Empty to avoid NullReferenceException

Comment: Thanks, i didn't think about it. Actually a have one more if statement that verify database connection.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating dymic proxy class which implements `ICustomersRepository` interface. Then you are exercising this generated proxy:

```
Mock<ICustomersRepository> mock = new Mock<ICustomersRepository>();
IEnumerable<string> countries = mock.Object.LoadCountries();
```

That is not very good idea. What do you verify with this test? Proxy generation? Proxy will not be used by your real code. You should use mocks to provide mocked dependencies for testing of real classes which are used by your application.

Actually I would not test that `LoadCountries()` calls `GetAll()` internally. Because this is a details of implementation, and that is not a business requirement for customers repository. I would write some acceptance/integration tests to verify that with given customers correct countries are returned.

UPDATE: Thus your `GetCountries()` filter is an extension, then you don't need to involve repository in its testing. Thats a simple static class, which can be tested on its own. **BUT** your test without interaction with database also will not be very valuable, because your extension composes query to datasource, which will be translated by query provider. I'll give you an example. If you have local method call (or method which canot be translated by your query provider):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IQueryable<string> GetCountries(this IQueryable<Customer> q) 
    {
        return q.GroupBy(c => c.Country).Select(x => LocalMethod(x.Key)); 
    }

    private static string LocalMethod(string country)
    {
        return country.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

Then following unit test will pass when you work with objects in-memory:

```
List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer> {
    new Customer { Country = "USA" },
    new Customer { Country = "Spain" }
};

var countries = Extensions.GetCountries(customers.AsQueryable());
Assert.AreEqual(countries.Count(), 2);
```

But when you'll run your application which queries SQL database with Entity Framework, then EF will fail to translate this filter into SQL.

Comment: I just want to verify how my filter is working. I don't need to test all database

Comment: @user3355354 how `GetCountries()` looks like?

Comment: public static IQueryable<string> GetCountries(this IQueryable<Customer> q)
        {
            return q.GroupBy(c => c.Country).Select(x => x.Key);
        }

Comment: @user3355354 see updated answer with expalanation why you should not unit-test this filter

Comment: Yes, maybe it test just GetCountries filter, but i have function in repository, that load customers list using paging and return current page, count of pages and IEnumerable<Customer>. And this function have a lot of operations and still using GetAll() method to get collection of Customers. How can I test it if i want to change Customers collection on my test array?

Comment: @user3355354 again, unit-test of in-memory query is not related to your real application. You should use acceptance/integration tests to verify that your query provider can translate query and that executed query returns correct data from database. You can't check this with unit test (well, you can analyze expression which was build, but thats very time consuming and brittle, ans still depends on whether provider can translate that expression)

Comment: And about your example. It works correct for database, baecause its using LINQ to SQL and GetAll() return context.Customers 
and it works for my test array because using LINQ to Objects and don't interact with database

Comment: @user3355354 with EF you'll get `Unhandled Exception: System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String LocalMethod(System.String)' method, and this me thod cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Answer (score 0):

But if you are trying to tests your repository and your LoadCountries is in your Repository layer, then you shouldn´t mock your repo.

you can´t use a repository method on a mock object ;) atleast without specifying some Return()

If you mock your repo is because you don´t want to connect to the database for the testa dn you want to retrieve mock data using for example:

```
List<Country> myList = //Fill your list with countries
repo.Setup(x => x.LoadCountries).Return(myList);
```

And then, use some other part to use this mock data.

But as I said, if you are trying to tests your repository, you shouldn´t mock it.

You mock your repository when you are trying to for example, tests some business part, and then you need some fake data from the database, the, mock the repo, and get you fake data ;)

If is this case, then:

```
Mock<ICustomersRepository> mock = new Mock<ICustomersRepository>();
mock.Setup(x => x.LoadCountries).Return(myList);
```

then for example, if from your business layer you ask in the constructor the ICustomersRepository, then you can create a instance f the business layer and pass this mock repo.

```
MyService service = new MyService(mock.Object);
service.LoadAll();
```

And if this LoadAll() use LoadCountries, then when this LoadAll call to LoadCountries it will get your mock data of countries!

I hope this helps!